# How to handle wrong drop location in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, imageview, gridpane

In my GUI I create some dices (ImageView) and I can drag and drop them in one specific GridPane. When I drop a dice into the specific GridPane, the dice disappears from the initial location and it moves to the right position. This works fine only if I choose the right drop location.

> The **problem** is how can I manage the wrong drop location?

Actually if I drop a dice in a wrong location (like outside the Gridpane) the dice disappears like it was moved to the right position.
I want to restore the dice to the original location if the dice isn't placed to the GridPane.

Is there a method can help me to check if I drop into the right location? Or something can prevent to drop into the wrong location?

Comment: Are you using clipboard+`DragEvent` or `MouseDragEvent`s?

Comment: DragEvent, now I am using setOnDragDetected, setOnDragOver and setOnDragDropped

Comment: I used `setonDraggedExited` in this example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432094/javafx-drag-and-drop-not-working-correctly?rq=1. It only removes the `Image` from the original location if it was dropped successfully.

Comment: when I run, my code thinks drop is going successful even if it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `transferMode` property of the `DragEvent` passed to the `onDragDone` event:

```
dragSource.setOnDragDone(evt -> {
    if (evt.getTransferMode() == null) {
        System.out.println("drag aborted");
    } else {
        System.out.println("drag successfully completed");
    }
});
```

**Note:** this requires you to mark the drag gesture as completed in the `onDragDropped` event handler using `setDropCompleted`. Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button source = new Button("Not dragged yet");
    Button target = new Button("target");

    HBox root = new HBox(20, source, target);

    source.setOnDragDetected(evt -> {
        Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(source.getText());
        db.setContent(content);
    });

    source.setOnDragDone(evt -> {
        source.setText(evt.getTransferMode() == null ? "failure" : "success");
    });

    target.setOnDragOver(evt -> {
        if (evt.getDragboard().hasString()) {
            evt.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
            evt.consume();
        }
    });
    target.setOnDragDropped(evt -> {
        String value = evt.getDragboard().getString();
        target.setText(value);
        evt.setDropCompleted(true);
        evt.consume();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: the problem is that my code print always "drag aborted" in both cases

Comment: @lordp you probably didn't call `setDropCompleted`. I added a working example.

Comment: thank you a lot in late, I resolve that, you were right!