# Javafx drag-drop does not work in the first time

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I just made a simple Application which includes FlowPane and some VBoxs which has a Button.

The Main class is like this.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Gallery a = new Gallery();
        a.setMaxWidth(200);
        a.setPrefWidth(200);
        Scene scene = new Scene(a); 

        stage.setTitle("Welcome to JavaFX!"); 
        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.sizeToScene(); 
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and this Gallery.class is the main back ground class which extends FlowPane.

```
public class Gallery extends FlowPane{

    public Gallery() {
        super();

        PlotterPanel p1 = new PlotterPanel(this, "B1" );
        getChildren().add(p1);

        PlotterPanel p2 = new PlotterPanel(this, "B2");
        getChildren().add(p2);

        PlotterPanel p3 = new PlotterPanel(this, "B3" );
        getChildren().add(p3);

        PlotterPanel p4 = new PlotterPanel(this, "B4" );
        getChildren().add(p4);

        PlotterPanel p5 = new PlotterPanel(this, "B5" );
        getChildren().add(p5);

        PlotterPanel p6 = new PlotterPanel(this, "B6" );
        getChildren().add(p6);


    }
}
```

And PlotterPanel is the VBox which has Button and can be drag-drop in the Gallery.

```
public class PlotterPanel extends VBox{

    private static final String TAB_DRAG_KEY = "titledpane";
    private ObjectProperty<VBox> draggingTab;
    private Gallery mgallery;
    private PlotterPanel self;

    public PlotterPanel(Gallery gallery, String name) {
        super();
        mgallery = gallery;
        setPrefWidth(100);
        setPrefHeight(100);
        self = this;

        Button btn = new Button(name);
        btn.setEffect(new DropShadow());
        getChildren().add(btn);

        draggingTab = new SimpleObjectProperty<VBox>();

        setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                final Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
                if (dragboard.hasString()
                        && TAB_DRAG_KEY.equals(dragboard.getString())
                        && draggingTab.get() != null) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(final DragEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                boolean success = false;
                if (db.hasString()) {
                    Pane parent = mgallery;
                    Object source = event.getGestureSource();
                    int sourceIndex = parent.getChildren().indexOf(source);
                    System.out.println(sourceIndex);
                    int targetIndex = parent.getChildren().indexOf(self);
                    System.out.println(targetIndex);
                    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>(parent.getChildren());
                    if (sourceIndex < targetIndex) {
                        Collections.rotate(
                                nodes.subList(sourceIndex, targetIndex + 1), -1);
                    } else {
                        Collections.rotate(
                                nodes.subList(targetIndex, sourceIndex + 1), 1);
                    }
                    parent.getChildren().clear();
                    parent.getChildren().addAll(nodes);
                    success = true;
                }
                event.setDropCompleted(success);
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Dragboard dragboard = self.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
                clipboardContent.putString(TAB_DRAG_KEY);
                dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);
                draggingTab.set(self);
                event.consume();
            }
        }); 
    }

}
```

The problem is that when i drag the PlotterPanel in the Gallery, it can`t be dragged at the first time. And i works after second try.
It shows the dragging box when i start dragging, but when i try to drop on the other Node the Mouse point shows the x sign.
but when the target is already tried Node to be dragged, i can drop on that Node.

How can i make the Drag-drop works well in JavaFX?

Comment: Is the `Node` you are trying to drop in to set up to receive those events?

Comment: yes, there is `setOnDragDropped` method. It works as i expect when i try with already tried Nodes. So i think that is not a problem.

Comment: It could be that you are missing some drag events. Make sure you use them. Especially onDragDone. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX drag and drop not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432094/javafx-drag-and-drop-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Are you trying to drag the button from one `Vbox` to another ?

Comment: @c0der No, i want to change the order of the VBox in the FlowPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your condition to accept the drag:

```
            if (dragboard.hasString()
                    && TAB_DRAG_KEY.equals(dragboard.getString())
                    && draggingTab.get() != null) {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                event.consume();
            }
```

You are checking the `draggingTab` of the target, not the source.  If the target hasn't been dragged itself, its `draggingTab` property will still be null.  If you have dragged the target already, then it won't be null and it will accept the drag.

Did you mean to make `draggingTab` static?